# Extracting information from text file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, project, data-analysis

I'm currently trying to extract data from a text file as part of an analytics challenge in my place of work. The text file is a bunch of data in lines with each heading/entry separated by a comma.

I've looked at several examples of text extraction online but the furthest I've gotten is getting one line in a single cell and then Excel freezing. All others have just frozen Excel after I've put in my conditions.

My current attempts involve the following:

```
Do Until EOF #1, textLine
Line Input #1, textLine

    Do Until Count = Len(text line) + 1
    Text = Text & Mid(textLine, Count, Count)
    If Right(text, 1) = "," Then
    textImport = Left(text, Count - 1)
    Cells(rowCount, column count) = textImport
    Text = ""
     columnCount = columnCount + 1
    Loop

    rowCount = rowCount + 1

Loop
```

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong? I can't share any of the data or the text file due to the nature of the challenge and the data involved.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the initial data and a sample of the desired result.

Comment: @VBasic2008 As above I can't provide actual data, however an example for the text file would be: pet name,favourite colour,number between 1 and 8735,city,animal (new line) Tyler,pink,646,London,dog (new line) Daisy,green,2,New York,cat. I want it in the form of a table with each heading in a cell and the corresponding info in the cells below. Some data points are blank and the text file is significantly larger than the example

Comment: No reason to reason to process each line character by character, just use `Split()`. Better yet, just open the file in Excel, since it already knows how to read csv files.

Comment: @JohnColeman hate to be a pain but could you explain this further? I'm learning at the moment after 3/4 years off after education so I'm extremely rusty

Comment: If you make sure the extension is CSV and just double click it, it should open in excel. Or you can open excel and import the data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I mean... That's just upsetting. It worked though! Thanks for the advice. Also JohnColeman would have resolved this if I hadn't had such a brain fart, so thanks to John too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## QueryTable Import

You can do this:

```
Sub QueryImport()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSource As String = "A1"      ' Source Range

    Dim vntFile As Variant  ' Source Array

    vntFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If vntFile <> False Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).QueryTables _
                .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & vntFile, _
                Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cSource))
            .Name = "Pets"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

which will open a dialog where you can pick the file, which will then be imported to Excel, and then you can manipulate it further which is out of scope due to lack of information. Post part of the result in another question to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this is not a CSV that can be opened in Excel.

```
Sub readCSVLikeFile()
    r = 1
    Open "<path of the file> For Input As #1
    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, txtline
        v = Split(txtline, ",")
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, UBound(v) + 1)) = v
        r = r + 1
    Wend
    Close #1

End Sub
```